# indefinite integral in terms of special functions

Tags: integration, special-functions

I have encountered the following integral
$$
I=\int \frac{1}{\log(x)+x} dx
$$

I know that the integral is not elementary. Is it possible to express the antiderivative in terms of known special functions?

Comment: If you want a series, it may help that $I'=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{x}(\frac{-\log(x)}{x})^n$ (Puiseux series)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any special function for this integral. What you could to is to writs
$$\frac{1}{\log(x)+x}=\frac 1 x \,\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{\log (x)}{x}}=\frac 1 x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{-(n+1)}\log^n(x)$$ Now
$$I_n=\int x^{-(n+1)}\log^n(x)\,dx=\int t^n \, e^{-n t}\, dt=-n^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (n+1,n t)$$
$$I_n==-n^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (n+1,n \log(x))$$

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ the upper incomplete Gamma function?